# Calling Third-party APIs from Angular (UiPath Orchestrator API)

Tags: angular, uipath-orchestrator

I have created an app usign Django and Angular, I would like to display the Jobs executed for particular process using UiPath Orchestratr API. I tested the API on Postman and it was working fine. But when I implemented it in my Angular app, I got 404 error.
What could I possibly doing wrong?

service

```
public get_jobs() {
let UiPath_token = 'Bearer abc'
let myheader = new HttpHeaders({ 'Authorization': UiPath_token,'$top':'3', '$filter':"Release/Name eq 'process_name'"});
console.log(UiPath_token);
return this.httpWithoutInterceptor.get<any>(this.UiPath, {headers:myheader}).subscribe(data=>{
  let job_list=JSON.parse(data);
  console.log("Jobs :", job_list);});
```

[image]

[image]

Error after changes as suggested by Kanishk Anand:
[image]

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have used `${this.uiPath}, {headers: myheader}}` which "stringifies" the object, hence, causing the issue. You should pass the URL as separate argument and headers as part of `options`.

```
public get_jobs() {
let UiPath_token = 'Bearer abc'
let myheader = new HttpHeaders({ 'Authorization': UiPath_token,'$top':'3', '$filter':"Release/Name eq 'process_name'"});

console.log(UiPath_token);

return this.httpWithoutInterceptor.get<any>(this.UiPath, {headers:myheader}).subscribe(data=>{
  let job_list=JSON.parse(data);
  console.log("Jobs :", job_list);
});
```

For CORS error, here are your options :

1. Enable the CORS headers at the API endpoint server to support `localhost:4200`
2. Proxy the API call to your Django server and hit the API endpoint from there. This will require you to create a separate API endpoint on Django for Angular to hit from where you finally hit the desired endpoint

More details on CORS headers : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS

Comment: Hi, thankl you. I changed my code as you had pointed out. But now I get CORS errors. I am adding a screenshot to my question

Comment: @alucor-it You need to enable CORS headers on your Django server to remove the CORS error. More details on CORS : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS